# Under what circumstances can I lose exactly 1 reputation point from the removal of a user?

Tags: support, reputation

Today, I saw a very odd reputation message on [my account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/codegnome?tab=reputation):

```
-1  3 hours ago     removed     User was removed
```

Obviously, I lose reputation points if I'm upvoted by someone who is later removed, or gain reputation points if I'm downvoted by someone who is eventually removed. So far, so good.

Since I'm not sure under what circumstances a user can net me a single reputation point in the first place, how can I lose exactly one reputation point from the removal of that user?

Comment: Were you rep-capped on that day already? I'd guess you were 1 point away from rep cap when they upvoted you.

Answer (score 5):

There are essentially an infinite number of possibilities. Since all the votes which get reversed are *combined* for that statement, there's no way to really know *how many* votes are being counted in that total. As suggested in the comments, it could be a rep-cappred vote, ot maybe the user had upvoted one of your question and downvoted two of your other posts (+5 -2 -2 = +1 * -1 = -1). You don't know how many votes, when, or on what that user had previously cast on your content.